# Why call moveToFirst() after making query in database android

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I am learning sqlite in android. Today I came across a code for finding specific entry in dateabase and returning it (for dispalying to user). I am little confused on what is happening in the code. First the programmer calls query method, then moves the cursor to first row.

Why has he called moveTofirst() method? Wouldn't this method place the cursor in the start of the database resulting in the lose of what the query method has returned.

```
Cursor c = database.query(TABLE_NAME,columns, NAME_COL+ "="+ findname, null,null,null,null);

if(c!=null)
{
   c.moveToFirst();
   name= c.getString(1);
   return name;
}
```

Regards.

Comment: The answer is in the question: "_moves the cursor to first row_" (of the result of the query)

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#moveToFirst()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Based on the docs the description of moveToFirst() is

> Move the cursor to the first row.

So basically, you're setting the cursor to the first row of the results (and not the table itself) since the cursor contains only the rows matching your query and not all the rows from the table (unless you queried for them).

Answer (score 2):

Another reason why you might want to call moveToFirst() is that when you first query, the cursor starts at index -1. Thus, you have to call moveToFirst() or any other moveTo.. function in order to access a proper row.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `moveToFirst()` allows you to test whether the query returned an `empty` set (by testing the `return` value) and it moves the `cursor` to the first result (when the set is not `empty`).

for more info at [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12445010/what-is-the-use-of-movetofirst-in-sqlite-cursors)

Answer (score 1):

When you make a query, you get back all the result, "encapsulated" in a `Cursor` object. This cursor contains all the rows you asked for, but not the entire database !!

For seeing the results, you have to move the Cursor through the rows it contains. Just after the query, the cursor doesn't point on anything. Calling `moveToFirst()` make the Cursor pointing the first row of the result of your query.

Also, as said in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17320323/1387484) of your question, you're also able to test if some results was actually returned.