# SQLite select not working with Where clause

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am trying to get data from my SQLite table, I am running this query:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
// int memberId = 1234
Cursor rs = db.rawQuery("select username, password from users where memberId = ? limit 1", new String[]{String.valueOf(memberId)});
System.err.println("Rows: " + rs.getCount());
```

The output is `Rows: 0`

But when I run this query:

```
Cursor rs = db.rawQuery("select username, password, memberId from users limit 1", new String[]{});
rs.moveToFirst();
System.err.println(rs.getString(0) + ":" + rs.getString(1) + ":" + rs.getString(2));
```

I get `username:xxxx:1234`

How come when I add a `where` clause this is breaking?

Comment: Perhaps your `memberId` that you are using as the query parameter does not exist in the table.

Comment: or your `new String...` business is producing a value which doesn't match what's in the db.

Comment: @CommonsWare it does exist, I just checked.

Comment: @MarcB the value in the database is an int, could that be an issue?

Comment: My memory of cursors may be failing me, but would the fact that you call `rs.moveToFirst()` on the second example be the differing factor?

Comment: I got it, it was because I didn't define a data type for that column

Answer (score 1):

As @Ryan Naddy pointed out - the difference between exposition one and exposition 2 is that you call "moveToFirst()" - you need to do this as the cursor is positioned before the first entry.

See this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12445010/what-is-the-use-of-movetofirst-in-sqlite-cursors).