# "else" not working

Tags: java, android, sqlite, if-statement

```
public void randomFood (View view){
    Cursor mCursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT name FROM member ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1", null);
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
        String name = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex("name"));
        Log.i("===============", name);
        AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        dialog.setTitle("This is your dog name");
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        dialog.setMessage(name);
        dialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        dialog.show();
    }

    else{
        AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        dialog.setTitle("Wait!!");
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        dialog.setMessage("Please add information");
        dialog.setPositiveButton("Go", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Random.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        dialog.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        dialog.show();
    }
}
```

when I click a button. if database has a information `(!mCursor.equals(null)or(mCursor != null)`, it random and show dialog. But if database don't has information ... "else" not working.

I don't know when database don't has information, "mCursor" equal null???

Comment: It is always true bcoz one entry should be return....

Comment: debug for cursor value when there are no records and modify your if statement accordingly

Comment: try `if(mCursor == null)` in place of `esle`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is The use of moveToFirst () in SQLite Cursors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12445010/what-is-the-use-of-movetofirst-in-sqlite-cursors)

Comment: hi, your query always return a value. Isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change

`if (mCursor != null)`

**to**

`if (mCursor != null &&  mCursor.moveToFirst())`

This is because cursor can be empty i.e. your query was executed successfully but number of selected rows is 0.

Answer (score 2):

That's because there's **always a non null value returned** - *even* in the case where you receive no rows (and the SQL doesn't throw an `Exception`)

You' be better of to recode your if to

```
if(mCursor.getCount() > 0) {
```

Answer (score 0):

> rawQuery() will either return a Cursor object or it will throw an
>   exception. It will never return null.

instead try with this

```
if(mCursor.moveToFirst())
{

}
else
{

}
```