# Exception when request an image from database

Tags: android, sqlite

My Cursor is always -1 when i send a request to my database (sqlite) to load an image.

```
public Cursor getData(int id){

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE ID = " + id;
        Log.d(TAG, query);
        Cursor data = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        return data;
}
```

The result is an app crash and this log in the logcat:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.master.tobias.phono, PID: 10721
>       android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1

Edit: The query works fine with the DB Browser for SQLite.

Comment: please post you full code

Comment: you did not call `moveToNext()` method

Comment: Here is nice explanation https://stackoverflow.com/a/12445030/1854103. Basically you should call data.moveToFirst() (in your case is cursor named data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `cursor.moveToFirst()` before accessing the cursor data

Answer (score 0):

**try this one**

```
public Cursor getData(int id){

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE ID = " + id;
        Log.d(TAG, query);
        Cursor cursor= db.rawQuery(query, null);
        while(cursor.moveToFirst()){
          //get your value over here
        }
        return data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's also beneficial to look at the Android documentation of methods as it provides more information as to what the method if expecting as parameters and will be returning. Firstly, the db.rawQuery

> Runs the provided SQL and returns a Cursor over the result set.
>   [SQLiteDatabase](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#query%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

As for the cursor, you need to check the existence of an object with the Cursor variable. This can be done via using the following method:

```
cursor.moveToFirst();
```

> Move the cursor to the next row. 
>   This method will return false if the cursor is already past the last entry in the result set.
>   [Cursor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor#moveToFirst())

This method will return a boolean which you can use for further validation. If the boolean is false, the cursor doesn't contain any data/objects within. If it's true, you know you have existence of the data.
Therefore, you are missing this functionality where you'll need to move the object to the first row which will allow you to determine if the query was empty or not.